# Bluetooth Keyboard on 2 Distros

Tags: networking, dual-boot, keyboard, bluetooth

I have the K810 Keyboard that can have up to 3 Bluetooth connections. So I dual boot Ubuntu and Arch, and I want to use this Bluetooth Keyboard for both of them.

The problem is that I set 1 of the connections to be connected to Ubuntu, and when I try to set up to 2nd connection to Arch, it makes the 1st connection nonexistent. And when I try to use the 2nd connection in Ubuntu, it detects it but cannot connect to it, so I have to remove it and pair it up again. Each time I switch from Ubuntu and Arch, or Arch and Ubuntu, I have continuously pair it each time!

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Could you please clarify which keyboard model from which manufacturer this is and how exactly you go about pairing it with Ubuntu?

Comment: @DavidFoerster My Keyboard is the K810 from Logitech and I use bluetoothctrl... So basically when I do: sudo bluetoothctrl, power on. remove <Keyboard MAC>, scan on, pair <Keyboard MAC>, connect <"">. And I have to do this everytime I switch distros...

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be possible by pairing in Ubuntu and then copying the key value in the

```
/var/lib/bluetooth/{controllerMAC}/{DeviceMAC}/info
```

file and put the key value in the file in Arch
The {controllerMAC} and {DeviceMAC} info can be found using `bluetoothctl`

An example info file

```
[General]
Name=MDR-ZX770BT
Class=0x240404
SupportedTechnologies=BR/EDR;
Trusted=true
Blocked=false
Services=00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;
```

[LinkKey]
Key={omitted}
Type=4
PINLength=0

I have tested this on a dual boot Ubuntu 16.04/LM18 machine and it does work

Just use the same bluetooth setting on the keyboard, don't switch to #2 for the other OS as usually all the keyboard will see is the MAC address of the PC's bluetooth and the key

Comment: Ah I see... Because I have the same controller MAC I can just simply cp the folder and put it in Arch... Hmm... I'll try it! I have the folder and I see all the info there...

Comment: Hmm... It doesn't seem to work... It does not detect the new settings at all?... Could you specifically tell me how you did it?

Comment: Wait a minute it works! I had make sure that both of them were connected so they had both a folder with my keyboard address and then only copy paste the "info" folder! Thanks @Jeremy31 !